# Wordpress links in wamp not working at all

Tags: wordpress, localhost, wamp

I am building a Wordpress website in localhost using WAMP.

Everything seems to be working smoothly except for some details :

1 - Accessing the project from " Your project " in wamp www/index.php returns a web browser dns error.

2 - Uploading media files from the " add media " in admin workspace succeeds to place the picture ( in its various resizes ) in wp-content/uploads/ folder but don't get called. ( Displays the broken image link icon in the article, as well as in the media library and any other place ).

3 - Any link manually typed in the browser returns a dns error except for the http://localhost/ ( to display the wamp index page ) or http://localhost/myproject (home page for the wordpress website I'm building.)

Wamp version : WampServer Version 2.5
Wordpress version : 4
OS : Win 7 professional
Browsers : IE 11, Chrome, Firefox, Opera

What's not working properly ?
How may I make it work ?

Thank you

TL; DR :
Briefly, my issue is :
1 - Uploaded pictures to wordpress website display broking image link
2 - Links typed manually into the browser return dns error

Comment: i can't understand what you are not getting explain briefly

Answer (score 0):

Can you test it with XAMPP instead of wamp?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I will try. I am going to download XAMPP. Will I just have to export my data base ?

Comment: Export your DB with phpmyadmin und copy the used folder in /htdocs

Comment: Excellent thank you. By used folder, you mean, the folder where my wordpress website's files are. Right ?

Comment: Hey Polaris. Installation went smoothly. Still the same problem. Any idea as to what seems to cause it ? I'm starting to think it's some php file in Wordpress.